# How can I add each element from a QListView into a vector?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

just want to put it out there that I am a beginner at C++. I'm trying get all the elements in my QListView and insert them into a Vector.

This is my loaddataset function which loads the files from a folder into the QListView:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionLoad_Dataset_triggered()
{
    QString sPath = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Choose catalog"), ".", QFileDialog::ReadOnly);
    QStringList filter;
    filter << QLatin1String("*.png");
    filter << QLatin1String("*.jpeg");
    filter << QLatin1String("*.jpg");
    filter << QLatin1String("*.gif");
    filter << QLatin1String("*.raw");
    filemodel -> setNameFilters(filter);

    ui -> imgList -> setRootIndex(filemodel -> setRootPath(sPath)); 
}
```

This is my QList function which then takes the file that the user clicks on and loads it onto a PixMap:

```
void MainWindow::on_imgList_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    imgNames = {};

    QString sPath = filemodel -> fileInfo(index).path();

    QString paths = filemodel -> fileInfo(index).fileName();

    //this kind of does it but instead of pushing them all it only pushes the ones that the user has clicked on instead of all
    imgNames.push_back(paths);

    map -> filename = filemodel -> filePath(index);

    map -> loadImage(scene);
    scene -> addItem(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of all items from `QListView` like this:

```cpp
    auto* m = qobject_cast<QStringListModel*>(ui->listView->model());
    const QStringList &list = m->stringList();
    QVector<QString> vec;
    std::vector<QString> vec2;
    for (const auto& l : list) {
        //using QVector
        vec.append(l);
        //or std::vector
        vec2.push_back(l);
        qDebug() << l;
    }
```

As a side note, you can initialize your `QStringList` using initializer list like this:

```cpp
QStringList list = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};
```

which will be faster and is much cleaner.

Comment: QStringList list = m->stringList(); seems to be crashing my code :/ and also thank you for the side note looks much cleaner already!!

Comment: that must be because `m == nullptr` or invalid, and if you try to access a null pointer, crash.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is how to initialize a `QStringList`, with C++11 you can use an [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```cpp
const auto filter = QStringList{
  QLatin1String("*.png"), 
  QLatin1String("*.jpeg"), 
  QLatin1String("*.jpg"),
  QLatin1String("*.gif"),
  QLatin1String("*.raw") };
filemodel -> setNameFilters( filter );
```

If fact, you can drop the explicit instance of `QStringList` and shorten it to:

```cpp
filemodel -> setNameFilters( {
  QLatin1String("*.png"), 
  QLatin1String("*.jpeg"), 
  QLatin1String("*.jpg"),
  QLatin1String("*.gif"),
  QLatin1String("*.raw") } );
```

If you're forcing all strings to be translated / Unicode-friendly except those explicitly opted out of (the usual use case for `QLatin1String`), you might also consider defining your own string [literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) to make it more concise:

```cpp
inline QLatin1String operator""_QL1( const char* str, std::size_t len ) 
{ return QLatin1String( str, len ); }
...
filemodel -> setNameFilters( { "*.png"_QL1, "*.jpeg"_QL1, "*.jpg"_QL1, 
                               "*.gif"_QL1, "*.raw"_QL1 } );
```

Comment: Thank you!! However it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: I was looking for the answer above, getting all the elements of a QListView and insterting them into a QVector